# how to fetch next/previous rows from database using ajax

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to fetch next previous rows from mysql database to ajax

I managed to do it but i have a problem when i click previous button it always send me back to the first result

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var card_id = document.getElementById('cardid').value
        $(document).on('click', '#previous', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"includes/fetchcards.php",
                method:"POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{card_id:card_id,prev:1},
                success:function(data)
                {

                    $('#cardfront').text(data.front)
                    $('#cardback').text(data.back);
                    card_id = data.id
                    alert(card_id)



                }
            });
        });

        $(document).on('click', '#next', function(){
            $.ajax({
                url:"includes/fetchcards.php",
                method:"POST",
                dataType: 'json',
                data:{card_id:card_id, next:1},
                success:function(data)
                {
                    $('#cardfront').html(data.front)
                    $('#cardback').html(data.back);
                    card_id = data.id
                    alert(card_id)



                }
            });
        });

    });
</script>
```

php code

```
<?php
include 'config.php';
if(isset($_POST["card_id"]))
{
    $card_id = $_POST["card_id"];
    if(isset($_POST["next"])){
        $db->where("id", $card_id,  ">") ;
        $flaschcard = $db->getOne('cards') ;
    }
    if(isset($_POST["prev"])){
        $db->where("id", $card_id,  "<") ;
        $flaschcard = $db->getOne('cards') ;
    }
    if(isset($flaschcard)) {
        echo json_encode($flaschcard);
    }
}
```

I expect that when i click previous button it shows the previous row but it always send me back to the first result

Comment: You need to show us your php code as well

Comment: i have updated with my php code

Comment: Imagine your `where` will split the result in half. If you try to fetch the next one, you can take the first entry of the second half. If you try to fetch the previous one, you can't take the first entry of the first half since that's the first entry of them all. You get around this by reversing the order

Comment: i use PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class https://github.com/ThingEngineer/PHP-MySQLi-Database-Class#select-query

here is an example of how it works 

$db->where ('id', 50, ">=");
// or $db->where ('id', Array ('>=' => 50));
$results = $db->get ('users');
// Gives: SELECT * FROM users WHERE id >= 50;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if(isset($_POST["prev"])){
    $db->where("id", $card_id,  "<") ;
    $db->orderBy("id", "desc"); // Reverse the order to fetch the last one
    $flaschcard = $db->getOne('cards') ;
}
```